# Is there any command for installing an app in Genymotion?

Tags: android, terminal, adb, simulator, genymotion

Hey guise I want to install an app on several devices in Genymotion by using terminal in ubuntu. Each time I do this:

> adb install package.app

It gives me the below error:

```
error: more than one device/emulator
 - waiting for device -
 error: more than one device/emulator
```

I also read about

> adb -s udid uninstall package.app

but this is not the solve I want. I don't want to use udid and also I don't know which device has my app from before?

Any suggestions?!

Comment: stop any one emulator and try gain

Comment: It didn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

adb help is not extremely clear on what to do:

```
-d                        - directs command to the only connected USB device...
-e                        - directs command to the only running emulator...
-s <serial number>        ...
-p <product name or path> ...
```

The flag you decide to use has to come before the actual adb command:

```
adb -e install path/to/app.apk
```

Comment: This error raise up because of I am running more than one emulator devices. If I run just one it works fine but the problem is that I want running adb commands on all connected devices!

Comment: Get a list of all connected devices / emulators. In a loop, go execute the install command for each device / emulator and provide the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass adb commands when there are more than one device connected and running at the same time ; this is a limitation with adb.

Comment: I think it's not true there are several ways for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Wow finally!
I found this command as my answer:

> adb devices | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % install app.apk

Thanks to [sivze](https://gist.github.com/christopherperry/3208109#gistcomment-2059437)